# bull repeatable jobs left in Redis

Tags: bull-queue

I started using the repeatable jobs in bull and everything seems to be working well for me.  However, I noticed that each iteration leaves a job in Redis:

18. "test:foo:repeat:7a140b0cf5b3ee29cb164b7c9cc03bc3:1619132310000"
19. "test:foo:repeat:7a140b0cf5b3ee29cb164b7c9cc03bc3:1619132280000"
20. "test:foo:repeat:7a140b0cf5b3ee29cb164b7c9cc03bc3:1619132360000"

and the list keeps growing.  I tried to do a job.remove() within the process function, but it threw an error... can't remove repeatable jobs I guess.  I'm assuming these will eventually be cleaned up by Redis, but is there something more proactive I can do to keep Redis clean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to add the 'removeOnComplete' value to the jobOptions.

Comment: After 3 hours of googling I finally found it.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can also clean the completed jobs by

```
queue.clean(0, 'completed');
```

Refer to https://github.com/OptimalBits/bull/issues/709#issuecomment-344561983